# Can't use read.table() inside foreach loop (doSMP)

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use doSMP / foreach to parallelize some code in R.

I had a huge 2d matrix of genetic data - 10,000 observations (rows), and 3 million variables (columns). I had to split this data up into chunks of 1000 variables because of memory issues.

I want to read in each file, do some stats, and write out those results to a file. This is easy with a for loop, but I want to use foreach to speed it up. Here's what I'm doing:

```
# load doSMP, foreach, iterators, codetools
require(doSMP)

# files i'm processing
print(filelist <- system("ls matrix1k.*.txt", T))

#initialize processes
w <- startWorkers(2)
registerDoSMP(w)

# for each file, read into memory, do some stuff, write out results.
foreach (i =  1:length(filelist)) %dopar% {
    print(i)
    file <- filelist[i]
    print(file)
    thisfile <- read.table(file,header=T) 
    # here i'll do stuff using that file
    # here i'll write out results of the stuff I do above
}

#stop processes
stopWorkers(w)
```

But this results in an error: `Error in { : task 2 failed - "cannot open the connection"`. When I change the `%dopar%` to `%do%`, there's no issue at all.

Comment: Not answering your question, but putting the data into a NetCDF file (with package ncdf) would make it easy and fast to input chunks of data; using `scan()` instead of `read.table` will be much faster. And I'd guess opening the files outside the loop (`?file`) might work

Comment: Still now answering your question, but a halfway house to what @Martin suggests is to use the `colClasses` argument in `read.table`. This can really speed things up.

Comment: could you give a bit more detail? 1) did it open some files, or does it fail immediately? 2) are you writing to different files or to one and the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that parallel input does speed up things. The limiting factor is the disk controller, so it does not help when you open up 2 connections and read the data because it has to go through the disk controller anyway. Disk IO is a serial job (sadly) unless you have a RAID array with several disk controllers. Parallel IO only works well on clusters where each machine has its own disk.

Comment: In theory you are right.  However, in practice with certain size data sets in R using the functions OP is using (probably for the very inefficiency reasons mentioned in the comments above), I have seen considerable speed increases using parallel code.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your foreach loop you must call the package tha you are going to use.

**EXAMPLE:**

*i)*

```
foreach (i =  1:length(filelist), .packages = "rgdal") %dopar% ......
```

in your case, you shoud call a vector of packages.

**EXAMPLE 2:**

*ii)*

```
package.vector <- c("package.1","package.2",etc)

foreach (i =  1:length(filelist), .packages = package.vector) %dopar% ......
```

I recomend you call all packages that you are using